# Clearing previous plot on .Net chart c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Sorry if this question has already been asked, I can't find anything similar. 
I have a load button which load an image, and a button to plot a graph on a chart everytime I click the plot button.

I load the first image, and plot successfully with my code,
When I load my second image, and click the plot again , it does plot out but and overlap on top of each other . However, i only want the latest plot result, is there any way to get rid of the old one?

The reason i don't want the old one is because the old result sometimes have a much different dimension from the new one. the Scale starts getting weird when they tried to overlap each other on the same picturebox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some code samples of your implementation would be helpful.

Comment: It depends what you do before: You clear the points of a series by series.Points.Clear() and you clear all series by chart.Series.Clear()

Comment: @rageit my code is super long. But I can show you tell you how to implement my code without knowing what they are doing.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h15kg6qhs8drie2/NEWVSCAMERANEW.rar

Comment: Can you first click the load image button. and press plot button next to the chart. load another image, and press plot button again, then you will see both images overlap on top of each other.

Comment: Please use images smaller than 640x360 size with the specified format, as I haven't generalised the code to any size yet.

Comment: Post the relevant bits of your code, and post screenshots of your application in action. e.g., posting the code for what happens when you "click the plot again" would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the points in all of the series in the chart:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].Series[0].Points.Clear();
```

and then add the new points in as usual.

Comment: I tried.. it shows a big white box with a red cross at the middle.

Comment: And then you added the new points? The big red X of doom means something went wrong during the painting - the axis min and max are equal, for example.

Answer (score 0):

To clear current points in a chart use:

chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();

or

chart1.Series["NameOfYourSeries"].Points.Clear();

If you use

chart1.Series.Clear();

Then try and use:

chart1.Series["0"].Points.AddXY(somevalue,somevalue);

You will get a fault.